# Load large data set with WPF ContextMenu for RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, performance, contextmenu, ui-virtualization

I'm into a situation where the number of items of a ContextMenu has gone to a number like 3 thousand. In this scenario, the ContextMenu takes lot of time in loading itself. I'm trying to do UI Virtualization but without any luck.

The sample code is as follows:

```
 <RichTextBox x:Name="FMWpfPopupControlHost" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Height="600" Focusable="True" Loaded="onLoaded1">
        <RichTextBox.ContextMenu >
            <ContextMenu VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" ItemsSource="{Binding GetLabel, Source ={StaticResource model}}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Initialized="TextBlock_Initialized" Text="{Binding getLabel}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <ContextMenu.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>                        
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemsPanel>
                <ContextMenu.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}" Focusable="False">
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.Template>
            </ContextMenu>
        </RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Please guide me how can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Harsh Gupta

Comment: 3000 items in context menu?? It seems to me that usability suffers a lot. I hardly believe that something can be done with productivity. The only idea is not to use event in menu item template. Do you really need placing so much items in context menu?

Comment: I've found the solution and it is just that Height/MaxHeight field for ContextMenu was required.